# Translations for non dynamic data

Tags: php, mysql, language-translation

I am currently making a web page with dynamic content from a database (a restaurant menu) storing item names, prices, yada yada. The restaurant usually caters to English and Japanese. I have stored the titles of the items in the database as English and Japanese, however when it comes to the type of the item, for example, Type: Drink, Type of Drink: Coffee I can obviously store the type of item alongside the item in the database, but it hardly seems worth it to store it twice as two different languages in the the database which would also make the form to add a new item a pain.

What is the best way to go about translating those little tiny pieces of information, like "Coffee", "Wine", "Click Here", "Menus", and using them on the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use gettext extension for translation static or predefined info on web page.

See manual http://php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php

Example http://mel.melaxis.com/devblog/2005/08/06/localizing-php-web-sites-using-gettext/

Comment: This seems pretty simple in a non-simple sort of way. I like it so I'll give it a try. I was about to start making an XML file with all the text I need translated! Nightmare.

Answer (score 1):

I would store it in both languages, it makes the most sense to me. I don't see why you would go and do a request to your translation system each time you want to show any page in your menu.

If you are using an automatic translation system that you really trust, one thing that you could do is use it when adding a new item to make a suggestion. So, after the user enters the word in English on the form, automatically attempt to translate that into Japanese and put it in the Japanese field. If the user is satisfied with the translation, that's it for that task, otherwise he/she inputs with a better one.

Comment: Storing in both languages would be epically redundant though. I know redundancy is useful when programming, but storing both would be ridiculous. And plus there are other several columns in the database that are in English, like is the item available. I'm not going to have an English available column with yes as the answer and an あります column with はい as the answer multiple times for the same thing.

Comment: It seems to me that the redundancy you are worried about is in your DB  schema, not in maintaining a translation. I never suggested that you store the translation more than once. It's up to you how you store this, whether it's next to the data in English where that is stored or you make a separate "translation" table. Why store it more than once? Anyway, you either have to do automated translation (and take the risk of error and do the extra requests every time) or you store the translated words somewhere. I'm not exactly sure what option you are hoping for that isn't one of these.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using any phph5 based framework , major framework have localization support like zend has Zend_Locale 
if you want your own  translation dictionary , keep key value pair data in database table and memcached between application and DB   , so static data will be cached for particular expiry time and  data base load will be get decreased and fast retrieval of data